# Deny client code access to a third-party library in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dll, hide

I am writing a Library using C# and my library uses a third party .NET library. When I roll out my Library I have to include the third-party library as well along with my library. However I want to prevent users of my library (client code) from directly using the third-party library. Is there any way to enforce that at compile time or run time?

Comment: No, If I can access it, I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no legal issues with doing so, you can use ILMerge to merge the 3rd party library into your own one.

You have the option to make public classes from the 3rd party library internal. This way, clients of your code will not be able to access functionality from the 3rd party library (unless they do some kind of hack. For example, I am not sure if someone can use an internal class using some kind of [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) code).

Take a look at [this article](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ILMergeInternalize.aspx)

Comment: If you make the public 3rd party classes internal via ILMerge, you have more security. Security is a relative thing. You can also [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) your library (with the merged 3rd party library). This will make it even more secure. Other users will not even know that the third party library is in use.

Comment: I agree with you. If someone is is determined to hack it, he will. However, as I said, security is a relative thing. Maybe for the user who asked this question (user2242746), making it hard to use the 3rd party is enough (satisfies his requirement).

Comment: @user2242746, what level of security would you accept?